# REST upload filesize limited and timeout

Tags: ios, upload, onedrive

I use the REST api of onedrive and had 2 problems, as I upload file over than 100MB, even if the progress is done, the file list didn't show the file, so does it means that the REST limited the file size to 100MB? And the other question, I want to pause and resume the upload, design to use chunk but it told me that is not support yet, so I use the post but the post usually time out as the file is big and the network is not good enough(means the speed is slow  but stable).How can i solve this problem?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The current file size limit is 100 MB.

As far as pause and resume, the closest thing we offer is resumable downloads:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631844.aspx

Comment: I am sorry but I need the upload resume, and the other question, if the file is large and network is not good, as 80M and 30K/S, we need much time to upload it but it always get a timeout error when uploading after about 1 minutes or 2, I doubt if there is a way to solve it, I think the chunck upload is a good way, just as dropbox and google drive did.